# Ruby on Rails tutorial chapter 1.4.3 (part about bitbucket)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I'm having some trouble setting up the bitbucket repo

```
humantoast@rails-tutorial:~/workspace/hello_app (master) $ git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:HumanToast/hello_app.git                                                                                                                          
fatal: remote origin already exists.
```

.

```
humantoast@rails-tutorial:~/workspace/hello_app (master) $ git push -u origin --all                                                                                                                                                                  
conq: repository does not exist.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: Both errors seem contradictory… Does your repo `hello_app` exist yet?

Comment: Agree with @CarlesJoveBuxeda Run `git remote -v` and share the output. Or try `git remote rm origin` and re-add it. See if that changes anything.

Answer (score 2):

I just want to say that I tried the following and it seems to have worked. Note that '<**username**>' refers to your username. If on a numbered list, replace <**username**> with your username.

Enter the numbered commands below into the terminal. '*Result*' is the output the terminal showed after the command was entered

1. git remote -v

*Result*

> origin  git@bucket.org:/hello_app.git (fetch)
> origin  git@bucket.org:/hello_app.git (push)

2. git remote rm origin

*Result*

No output in the terminal

3. git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:<**username**>/hello_app.git
4. git push -u origin --all # pushes up the repo and its refs for the first time

*Result* (note the 3 dots below refers to output on the terminal that I excluded due to it potentially containing confidential information)

> .
> .
> .
> Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?

5. yes

*Result*

> .
> .
> .
> To git@bitbucket.org:<**username**>/hello_app.git
>
> [new branch]      master -> master
> Branch master set up to track remote branch master from origin.

That seems to have done the trick. I wasted a day stuck so early in the book.